# How to convert a number in a string to an integer

Tags: ruby

I have an output like `"35%"` from one command, and I stripped `"%"`. Still, it's stored as a string. Is there a function to convert the string to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do `"35%".to_i` which produces `35`

For your exact problem:

```
puts 'true' if 35 == "35".to_i
```

output is:

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is "35%". Start reading your string character by character. First your pointer is at '3'. Subtract '0'(ASCII 0) from this and multiply the result by 10. Go to the next character, '5' in this case and again subtract '0' but multiply the result by 1. Now add the 2 results and what you get is integer type 35. So what you are basically doing is subtracting '0' from each character and multiplying it by 10^(its position), until you hit your terminator(% here).